# Get Request Is Considered As Post

Tags: php, post, module, yii

I have strange problem. I created a link:

```
<a href="/module/default/editEvent" style="font-size: 14px;">Edit Event</a>
```

and an action

```
public function actionEditEvent(){
      if(isset($_POST)){
          echo '<pre>';
          print_r($_POST);
          die;
      }
     $this->render('editEvent');
    }
```

when I click on link it prints blank array.

Can anyone tell me reason for that?<

[image]

Comment: `$_POST` is a superglobal array, so it will always be set regardless whether it has any value or not. Use `empty()` instead

Comment: @Dr. Dan put it as answer thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` is a superglobal array, so it will always be set regardless whether it has any value or not. Use `empty()` instead. You can also use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` as suggested by Alexander Taver

Answer (score 2):

Check $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] to find out whether it was GET or POST request

Answer (score 1):

As Dan Said $_POST is super global array , hence it will always be set

Instead you should use

!empty($_POST)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is a PHP global array it is avilable every where in php

you chancheck like these `if(count($_POST)>0)`

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since you're using yii, you can use:

```
if (Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest) {
    // Post request
}
```